# Selenium IDE - extract part of a text

Tags: string, selenium, text, extract

I've looked at a lot of answers to this question but I never seem to get the correct text that I need.

I am trying to extract a group name from a string, then check if that group name appears in a modal when I try to delete that group

The string is "`ABCDE 0`" where "`ABCDE`" is the group name.

The group name can change from time to time, so does the number beside it. Basically what I want to do is to remove the space and the number after it so all that is left is the group name.

I've tried `storedVars['LastGroup'].match(/\\d+/);` but I get the "`0`" instead of "`ABCDE`" when I run the test.

I've also tried `storeEval "${LastGroup}".split("")[${number}]` but all i get is "`A`"

I'm a newbie so I may be missing something but I'm not sure what it is. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
storeEval "${LastGroup}".split(" ")[0]
```

Note - There is blank "space" in split.

Comment: thank you! I can't believe the answer's so simple. Many thanks again!